# Calculate force due to gravity between two points

Tags: vectors

If I have point $A$ at $(0,0)$ and point $B$ at $(2,2)$, each with a mass of 100, I think I need to calculate the final force first $\frac{GMm}{r^2}$ and then work out the components of that force that go in the x and y direction.

Or can I just multiply the final force by the $ \Delta x$ or the $ \Delta y $?

Answer (score 0):

Using your formula for gravity you will find the force between them, along the vector $(2,2)$.

If you want to calculate the components in the x- and y-direction, you can use for example Pythagoras' theorem (the length of the hypotenuse is the force calculated).

Answer (score 0):

Well if you say "between two points" you don't need to multiply by anything or work out the components. The force from your formula is the force between to points along the line that connects them.

Comment: So i dont need to calculate $\frac{GMm}{r^2}$ cos(Delta Y) to get the x component or $\frac{GMm}{r^2}$ sin(Delta Y) to get the y

Comment: If you need the force (of gravity between those to points) projected along the axes then yes you do but if you need JUST the force acting between those masses you don't.

Comment: Right ok, thanks, because in my program, i'm trying to move objects by the force of gravity between them, and need an x component and y component to move them by

Comment: What program is that if i may ask?

Comment: One i'm writing, it will simulate gravity, but i need to calculate the gravitational force between two objects, then move them by the x component of the final force due to gravity, and by the y component of the force